# How to Convert/Migrate MS-SQL Server SELECT Query To Oracle & MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

In our product, we are extending support to Oracle & MySQL, so can anyone please help to migrate the following sample SQL query which works fine with MS-SQL Server, I already tried at my end but somehow it's not working for Oracle/MySQL, any help much appreciated & will convert rest of the queries by myself, thank you.

```
SELECT  A.SERVERID,A.DATAID 
                ,A.CREATETIMESTAMP AS 'Date Time'
                ,A.OBJECTINSTNAME
                ,A.PROJECTNAME 
                ,TEMP_IND_1.TEMP_ROW_NUM FROM DATALOG AS A WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                ( 
                    SELECT      DATAID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CREATETIMESTAMP DESC) AS TEMP_ROW_NUM FROM    DATALOG WITH (NOLOCK)

            WHERE PROJECTNAME='ProjectA'
            ) AS TEMP_IND_1 ON A.DATAID = TEMP_IND_1.DATAID

         WHERE TEMP_IND_1.TEMP_ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 50;
```

Comment: Pls include what you have tried and what error message or unexpected behaviour you encountered because as your question stands it basically read: pls do my work for me for free. I know this was not your intention, but still that's how it reads. Btw, I don't think you need to modify much in this query to make it work for oracle and mysql v8.

Comment: @Shadow Absolutely not, it depends on how you think & how you take it before deciding the intentions, I believe, thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use same query with removing `WITH (NOLOCK)` parts. As they have no effect in oracle and you don't need them in oracle. and also column alias is given without `as` keyword and column aliases has to be double quotes. So your query becomes like this :

```
SELECT  A.SERVERID,A.DATAID 
                ,A.CREATETIMESTAMP  "Date Time"
                ,A.OBJECTINSTNAME
                ,A.PROJECTNAME 
                ,TEMP_IND_1.TEMP_ROW_NUM FROM DATALOG A INNER JOIN
                ( 
                    SELECT DATAID,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CREATETIMESTAMP DESC) TEMP_ROW_NUM 
                           FROM    DATALOG 
            WHERE PROJECTNAME='ProjectA'
            ) TEMP_IND_1 ON A.DATAID = TEMP_IND_1.DATAID
         WHERE TEMP_IND_1.TEMP_ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 50;
```

**EDIT:**

For mysql there only thing you need to do alter session to set isolation level to `read uncommited` before executing your original query with out `with (no lock)` expressions.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
 -- your query without no lock expressions
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ ; -- set back to original isolation level
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick update, really appreciate that, it's quite insightful.

Comment: would you like to add any comments for MySQL syntax please, thanks.